# task scheduler stop running after 23 hour instead 1 day

Tags: windows-task-scheduler

i have set in the task scheduler that it will run a task

for 1 day every 10 minutes from 08:00:00

but the problem is that its stopping after 23 hour

mean , its stopped at 07:00:00 day after

and then in 08:00:00 its again to start run

and its on all computers , so 1 days its running for 23 hour?

its counting from 08:00:00 ?

[image]

Comment: On the task itself, there's a tab called log. What does it say when the task stops? Is it possible the computer is rebooting at that time and the task does not actually stop, but is aborted due to something else?

Comment: See also the Event Viewer, branch : Applications and Services Logs > Microsoft > Windows > TaskScheduler > Optional. Check all the task histories for events around 07:00.

Comment: Change it to be `One Time` **start date and time any previous date** on the hour mark you want it to start, then repeat every 10 minutes and for a duration of `Indefinitely`.  Now confirm it works as expected every 10 minutes moving forward—that's all that's needed, don't mess with the recur every 1 day if you want it to run every 10 minutes with Task Scheduler.

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle if i will do Indefinitely then in 08:00:00 it will run two task at the same time no?

Comment: If you have only one trigger with it defined like that, the start time will be whatever time to tell it to start. Then every 10 minutes, it will run the task again. I'm not sure what your task is, but Task Scheduler can execute it on a schedule. If the first task is not done by the time the next 10 minute period starts, then yes you will have two tasks running. Typically whatever you tell it to execute, it will do so only once. Script logic, executable logic, etc. may be a different story for what it does or launches once it is executed. Task Scheduler just works for automation—I do it a lot!

Comment: See here: https://i.imgur.com/KOOZFkh.png to maybe help explain some too but should be same concept for 10 minutes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/repetitionpattern.... See here too for more technical stuff: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/taskschedulerschema-repetition-triggerbasetype-element

Comment: @mikuzan So yes, perhaps you are noticing where 1 and 5 are both at with indefinitely.... perhaps you will get two running it this way: https://i.imgur.com/KrIr6Et.png. I think the trick here may be sliding over to the `settings` tab and setting the option to **not start a new instance** if the task is already running https://i.imgur.com/llWcRUn.png .... I would also consider setting the option to "stop the process is the task runs longer than X" where "X" is what makes sense there for too long for that process. Type in the value: https://i.imgur.com/VjOXe3Q.png

Comment: @harrymc the log tab in task scheduler on a specific task links all events from eventviewer related to this task.

Comment: @LPChip: Other events would also be interesting.